# How to separate categorical variables in modeling

Tags: regression, logistic, poisson-regression

Suppose I have a dataset as follows:

```
Product      Week    Type             Num times ad shown      Purchases
1         2/2/13    young,old,hipster        100                    5
```

and  I want understand what are characteristics of people that drive people to purchase a particular product(2 types). I have one column 'type' that shows the types of people who bought the product in that week. What would be a good modeling approach for this problem? Here is my approach. Transform the data set so that each level of the type variable gets its own row.

```
 Product      Week       Type      Num times ad shown     Purchases
    1         2/2/13    young       100                    5
    1         2/2/13    old         100                    5
    1         2/2/13   hipster      100                    5
```

The purchases are rare so most weeks the number of purchases is 0, and the range of values for the purchase variable is 0-200. I could either model the raw number of purchases, the proportion of purchases to the number of ads shown,  or transform purchases into a binary 0/1 variable and model the probability of a purchase. Respectively, I could either run a Poisson regression for counts, a CART model for the proportions, or a logistic regression for the binary outcome. I was just wondering if all three of these approaches are viable. Also is making the levels for the 'type' variable into its own row a viable option to capture what type of users buy the product?

Comment: What's your outcome?  Is the type of person the main covariate of interest?

Comment: I am interested in what factors increase the probability of purchase

Comment: "Run all three and cross-validate to see which one gives the best performance" is never a bad idea.

Comment: @ssdecontrol does my idea of have a new row of for each level of type as opposed to all levels of type in one row make sense?

Comment: @lord12 yup. like you said, it's the difference between a model for counts or a model for successes and failures. figure out which one you are interested in, and go from there.

Comment: I guess I'm more interested in probability of purchase so I will have a new line for each level of type and will transform my response variable to a 0/1 binary variable